# defining C++ preprocessor macro with quotation marks

Tags: c++, macros, preprocessor

I am trying to define a macro in C++ that puts quotes around a variable.

A simplified example of what I am trying to do is this:

```
#define PE(x) std::cout << "x" << std::endl;
```

and then when I type `PE(hello)` in my code, it should print `hello`; but instead it just prints `x`.

I know that if I make it:

```
#define PE(x) std::cout << x << std::endl;
```

and then type `PE("hello")` then it will work, but I would like to be able to be able to use it without the quotation marks.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the stringizing operator, `#`:

```
#define PE(x) std::cout << #x << std::endl;
```

I would suggest that you remove the semicolon from your macro, though.  So,

```
#define PE(x) std::cout << #x << std::endl
...
PE(hello);
```

Comment: thanks! thats exactly what i needed..

Comment: #define PE(BZL,YY) printf("ERROR - "  #BZL  ": result: 0x%08x!", YY);
Doing:int variable1=1; PE(Test1,variable1);  -->  Results printing: ERROR - Test1: result: 0x1!